How can I calculate the rate of overlapping events between two Poisson processes?
I have the following problem: I have 2 independent Poisson processes $N_1$ and $N_2$ with known rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively.
The events in each process have a well-defined duration, $D_1$ and $D_2$ respectively.
From that, I need to know: What is the rate in which simultaneous events will be observed?
That is: in what rate it happens that two events will overlap temporally, even if the overlap is arbitrarily small?
If necessary, I could take $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ and $D_1=D_2$ for a first approach, if being different makes it too difficult to solve.

For each arrival of $N_1$, the probability that at least one arrival of $N_2$ occurs within time $D_1$ afterwards is $1-e^{\lambda_2D_1}$. So the rate at which we have arrivals of $N_1$ followed by arrivals of $N_2$ in the required timeframe is $\lambda_1(1-e^{\lambda_2D_1})$. And likewise the rate at which we have arrivals of $N_2$ followed by arrivals of $N_1$ in the required timeframe is $\lambda_2(1-e^{\lambda_1D_2})$. How you combine these depends on what precise question you are asking. E.g. does an arrival of $N_1$, followed within time $D_1$ by an arrival of $N_2$, then followed within time $D_2$ by an arrival of $N_1$, count as one "simultaneous event" or two.
